# Vim plugins don't always load?

Tags: python, vim, plugins

I was trying to install `autoclose.vim` to Vim. I noticed I didn't have a `~/.vim/plugin` folder, so I accidentally made a `~/.vim/plugins` folder (notice the extra 's' in plugins). I then added `au FileType python set rtp += ~/.vim/plugins` to my .vimrc, because from what I've read, that will allow me to automatically source the scripts in that folder.

The plugin didn't load for me until I realized my mistake and took out the extra 's' from 'plugins'. I'm confused because this new path isn't even defined in my runtime path. I'm basically wondering why the plugin loaded when I had it in `~/.vim/plugin` but not in `~/.vim/plugins`?

Comment: I'm quite sure it's simply because `~/.vim/plugin` is predefined, whereas `~/.vim/plugins` is not.

Comment: Yeah that was my guess as well. However, say I want to have a custom directory to store my plugins, how could I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[:help load-plugins](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#load-plugins) outlines how plugins are loaded.

Adding a folder to your `rtp` alone does not suffice; it must have a `plugin` subdirectory. For example, given `:set rtp+=/tmp/foo`, a file `/tmp/foo/plugin/bar.vim` would be detected and loaded, but neither `/tmp/foo/plugins/bar.vim` nor `/tmp/foo/bar.vim` would be.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track with `set rtp+=...` but there's a bit more to it (`rtp` is non-recursive, help indexing, many corner cases) than what meets the eye so it is not a very good idea to do it by yourself. Unless you are ready for a months-long drop in productivity.

If you want to store all your plugins in a special directory you should use a proper `runtimepath`/plugin-management solution. I suggest [Pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) (`rtp`-manager) or [Vundle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3458) (plugin-manager) but there are many others.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Nikita Kouevda answer: modifying `rtp` on `FileType` event may be too late for vim to load any plugins from the modified runtimepath: if this event was launched after vimrc was sourced it is not guaranteed plugins from new addition will be loaded; if this event was launched after `VimEnter` event it is guaranteed plugins from new addition will *not* be sourced automatically.

If you want to *source* autoclose only when you edit python files you should use `:au FileType python :source ~/.vim/macros/autoclose.vim` (note: `macros` or any other subdirectory except `plugin` and directories found in `$VIMRUNTIME` or even any directory not found in runtimepath at all).

If you want to *use* autoclose only when you edit python files you should check out plugin source and documentation, there must be support on the plugin side for it to work.

// Or, if autoclose does not support this, use `:au FileType` command from above paragraph, but prepend `source` with something that records vim state (commands, mappings and autocommands), append same after `source`, find out differences in the state and delete the differences on each `:au BufEnter` if filetype is not python and restore them otherwise: hacky and may introduce strange bugs. The example of state-recording and diff-determining code may be found [here](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager/blob/extended-autoload/autoload/vam/autoloading.vim).

Comment: A simpler method I found for loading language-specific plugins was to throw them into the `.vim/ftplugin` folder. So if I wanted to only use autoclose, then I would put it in `ftplugin/python`. I tested it out and it worked only for python filetypes. You must also have `filetype plugin on` in your .vimrc. For any global plugins, I put them inside my `.vim/plugin` folder.

Comment: @Fumbster It is exactly the same solution as with `:au FileType`. It will *source* plugins when you edit python files, but being a global plugin once you source it you will *have it enabled* for all subsequent files you edit. I strongly suggest against using `ftplugin/python` for such plugins because it is semantics violation: plugins defining global mappings are **not** a filetype plugins and once enabled they will work for any subsequently loaded files thus they semantically belong to the same directory as `matchit.vim` (not-autoloaded global plugins).

Comment: @Fumbster * I, of course, meant “all subsequent files you edit *in the same vim session*.”

Comment: Interesting. Is there no workaround for this other then manually editing the global mappings on the plugin file? I am just asking hypothetically, as I have no intentions of actually doing this.

Answer (score 1):

All folders in the `rtp` (runtimepath) option need to have the same folder structure as your `$VIMRUNTIME` (`$VIMRUNTIME` is usually `/usr/share/vim/vim{version}`). So it should have the same subdirectory names e.g. `autoload`, `doc`, `plugin` (whichever you need, but having the same names is key). The plugins should be in their corresponding subdirectory.

Let's say you have `/path/to/dir` (in your case it's `~/.vim`) is in your `rtp`, `vim` will

- look for global plugins in `/path/to/dir/plugin`
- look for file-type plugins in `/path/to/dir/ftplugin`
- look for syntax files in `/path/to/dir/syntax`
- look for help files in `/path/to/dir/doc`

and so on...

`vim` only looks for a couple of recognized subdirectories<sup>†</sup> in `/path/to/dir`. If you have some unrecognized subdirectory name in there (like `/path/to/dir/plugins`), `vim` won't see it.

<sup>†</sup> "recognized" here means that a subdirectory of the same name can be found in `/usr/share/vim/vim{version}` or wherever you have `vim` installed.

Comment: Thanks for that. That helped me understand the runtimepath much more clearly. You are correct; as it turns out I used `plugins` instead of `plugin`, which  is not a Vim-recognized folder.